# System::String concatenation in managed c++ / CLI

Tags: .net, string, system, command-line-interface

I have seen the following construct in some of our code:

```
String^ channelName = gcnew String(pChannelData->UserLabel) + "_" + iChannelNameIndex;
```

Is this legal?  It seems like an allocation on the managed heap (for channelName) for a System::String of the size of pChannelData->UserLabel, but wouldn't take into account the additional characters.

Comment: It is fine, the C++/CLI compiler has built-in knowledge of string concatenation.  Your description of what you think happens isn't very close, just try this for yourself.  Look at the generated code with ildasm.exe to get insight.

Comment: So the following code would be 'as' correct?
    String^ channelName = pChannelData->UserLabel + "_" + iChannelNameIndex;

Comment: Maybe, probably not.  It depends on the type of UserLabel of course.  If it is an unmanaged C string then using the String constructor is required.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, using + for concatenation of System::String ^  is OK.